# PHP Include './' vs '../'

Tags: php, include

I've got a file structure at work that looks like this:

```
root/
├─ directory/
│  ├─ main.php
│  ├─ code1.php
│  ├─ code2.php
│  ├─ script.php
script.php
```

The `main.php` script has several `include()` statements, and a couple of them look like this: `include(code1.php)`, `include(code2.php)`. This makes perfect sense to me, as it's just looking the `code` script within `directory`, since `directory` is the `cwd`.

But then there's a line `include(.\script.php)`. I was cleaning up the codebase a bit (git was recently set up) and was looking to remove one of the duplicae `script.php` files, and based on the include statement, I removed the one inside of `directory` and left the one in `root`, because I thought the `.\` syntax meant to jump up one level and search there instead.

Well, that broke everything, and reverting the commit and putting `script.php` back into `directory` fixed it. I've done some searching and there's a *very* similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381382/php-include-vs) asking about the difference between just using a `..\` and using `\..\`, which I understand, but my question is what is the purpose of using just one period, like `.\`? Clearly it's not to jump up one level like I thought, but it also seems to be unnecessary when looking for a file that exists at the same level as the original script that was called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please write the correct path direction. `./` or `../`. One dot means current directory, two dots one directory up.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Ok gotcha.

Comment: @Cid Yes that is actually exactly what I was looking for, not sure how I didn't manage to come across it. That answer you linked to is maybe the most direct answer to one of my questions I've ever encountered haha. Thank you!

Comment: Relative paths often cause more problems than they solve. I suggest you compose absolute paths with `__DIR__` and `basename()` unless you have a strong reason to use relative paths.